# Negotiated fares as part of request in flight search APIs

Tags: sabre

Based on Sabre's solutions, Use case section, it is with the recommendation that the Bargain Finder Max API is used to retrieve fares for a particular segment. Am i looking at the wrong API because i am trying to build a request that allows private fare codes with the intention of pulling out negotiated fares.

Answer (score 0):

Bargain Finder Max accomplishes what you want to do - just use the TPA extension flexible fares - this is because private fares are not always the best. And then depending how the Airline loaded the fare use NegotiatedFareCode or CorporateID.

Comment: https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max/resources